# проверить, является ли переменная экземпляром класса

Tags: javascript

Пример: как проверить что переменная a является экземпляром класса B?

```js
let A = function() {
  class B {
    
  }
  return B;
}
let a = new A();
```

Comment: Метод [`instanceof()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof#See_also) может помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для проверки 'родства' нужно использовать `instanceof`. Хотя у этого способа есть [нюансы](https://learn.javascript.ru/instanceof).
В данном случае всё запутано - создаётся `A`, которое возвращает `B`, которое **пересоздаётся** в замыкании и недоступно внешне. Выходит `a` не потомок `A`, т. к. `A` возвращает `B`.
Хотя может показаться что стоит сделать так:

```
let a = new A, b = A(); // Создаём объект B и получаем ссылку на класс
console.info(a instanceof b); // true
```

Но это не будет работать, ибо при каждом вызове `A` создаётся новый класс `B` и уничтожается при выходе из `A` (ссылок на класс нету вне функции; сборщик его уберёт). Возвращаются **разные** объекты, хотя и с одним именем.

Вот так можно сделать:

```js
class B{} // Вытаскиваем из замыкания

let A = function(){
  return B;
};

// Сначала создаём A, потом B
let a = new (new A);

console.info(a instanceof B); // true
```

Comment: class B{
  f() {q = 2} 
  ff() {console.log(q);}
}

let A = function(){let q = 1;
  return B;
};

let a = new(new A());

console.info(a instanceof B);


Такой код, почему-то не выполняется, то есть B в таком случае не видит переменных внутри А

Comment: @Юрий, `q` установилась и уничтожилась в `A`. Нигде не указано что на неё ссылаются. Да, в методах класса используется переменная с именем `q`, но это не одна и та же переменная. С точки зрения интерпретатора (и моей, кстати).

Comment: Но тогда теряется смысл такой конструкции, как в вопросе, ведь он был в том, чтобы экземпляры класса B могли видеть внутренние переменные функции A

Comment: @Юрий, сборщик мусора следит за ссылками, если на что-то нет ссылок, это убирается из памяти. В Вашем примере ставится `q` и... `return`. Т. е. сборщик видит что переменная инициализирована и произошел выход. `q` (именно эта самая) нигде не используется, значит её удалить надобно. `q` в классе - это совершенно другая переменная, которую, кстати, никто не установил в методе, вот и ошибка.

Comment: Но как все таки сделать, чтобы он ее не удалял?

Comment: @Юрий, передай в конструктор. Так: https://jsfiddle.net/gvn5cma3/

Comment: В этом случае q уже не приватная

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38817/discussion-between-other-and-).

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как в конструкции с описание класса внутри функции, но вообще можно сделать так:

```
class B {

}
let a = new B();

console.log(a instanceof B);
```